# NodeJS HTTPS API testing with mocha and super test -"CERT_HAS_EXPIRED"

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mocha.js, supertest

I need to test an API served via `HTTPS` with `mocha` and `super test`

This is a gist of the server :

```
...
var app = express();
var _options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('my-key.pem');,
    cert: fs.readFileSync('my-cert.pem')
};

// Start HTTPS server
https.createServer(_options, app).listen(app.get('port'), app.get('ip'), function () {

 // ok or not logs

});
```

and this is the route to be tested

```
app.get('/hello',function (req, res) {
   res.json(200);
});
```

I'm trying to test with this code in `test/test.js`

```
    var supertest = require('supertest'),
        api = supertest('https://localhost:3000');

describe('Hello test', function () {

      it('hello', function (done) {

        api.get('/hello')
               .expect(200)
               .end(function (err, res) {
                                        if (err) {
                                                   done(err);
                                        } else {
                                                   done();
               }
         });
    });
});
```

but the test `FAILs` with the following error :

```
 Error: CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
  at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1349:32)
  at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
  at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:962:10)
  at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:463:15)
  at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
  at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
  at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:219:10)
  at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:209:5)
  at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
  at write (_stream_readable.js:573:24)
  at flow (_stream_readable.js:582:7)
  at Socket.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:614:5)
  at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
  at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
  at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:526:21)
```

While using plain `HTTP` the test is `PASSING`

Comment: What is the expiration date of "my-cert.pem"?  It's probably actually expired.

Comment: no the data it's o, cuz the api respond correctly

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken the error message at face value already? Is the certificate you are using to test expired? Is the clock way off on the machine? Also note that TLS certificates are associated with a host name and that host name is generally not "localhost" if you want to do anything useful. Assuming it's not the obvious error of the certificate being expired, try using exactly the correct hostname when connecting to your server.

Comment: cates work normally if I make the call with a normal rest client

Comment: if i update the expired data in the certificate. i'v this new ERROR 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654479/nodejs-https-api-testing-with-mocha-and-super-test-depth-zero-self-signed-cert